# How to create glasses virtual try-on with mediapipe with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality

Trying to create virtual try-on of glasses as it is shown below
[Glasses 3d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTTDh.gif)

with https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/javascript.html

Have not found any useful code example.

Comment: following the links you provided you'll find this: https://codepen.io/mediapipe
FaceMesh and FaceDetection appear promising

Comment: Why must it be mediapipe?   There is so many javascript examples using 3d include with facial glasses.  Example:  https://sbcode.net/threejs/glasses/

Comment: @Chizl the example you provided is not for AR?